# Missing Images on print

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, jquery-plugins

I want to open a new window/tab, put some HTML in the document, then bring up the browser print dialog to print that new window. I am using the following to accomplish this:

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.write(html);
w.document.close();
w.focus();
w.print();
w.close();
```

**HTML**:

```
<body>
  <img src='url1' />
  <img src='url2' />
  <img src='urln' />
</body>
```

This all works, the window pops up, and the print dialog is shown for the new page and prints all images fine. However, for some reason, some of images are printing, and instead the image `alt` message is printed.

There are lots of images, and they are dynamically generated on the server side (which takes about 1 second to load each).

What needs to be done to make sure all images are loaded and printed?

This happens in IE and Firefox that I've confirmed. I appreciate any help.

Comment: use `window.onload` - event will be fired after all resource are loaded

Comment: I did try putting <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = window.print;</script> on the page, and while it did print, I still had the same issue where images were missing.

Comment: use `img.onerror` event to hide the failed images `<img src="url" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>`

Comment: i think you are calling ajax calls to load the images. If so use the print command in ajax completed or success event.

Comment: I'm not using ajax, I am using HTML img tag and loading the image using URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [JS library that detect when images have been loaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/).

You can use it like this:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  imagesLoaded(document.body, function() {
    window.print();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for help! I used this plugin However still the print is missing the images intermittently.

Comment: Sorry, but if this plugin is not solving your problem, I don't have any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <title>Print Images</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    body, div, v\:image{
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    div{
        page-break-after:always;
    }
    v\:image{
        behavior: url(#default#VML);
        display: block;
        width: 1078px;
        height: 1527px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/life/public/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = $("td:[id^='tdImg']", window.opener.document);
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var image = $("<image/>");
                image.load(data.length, function(event){
                    try{
                        $("body").append($("<div/>").append($("<v\:image/>").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"))));
                        if($("body").find("v\\:image").length == event.data){
                            window.print();
                            window.close();
                        }
                    }catch(e){
                        alert(e.message);
                    }finally{
                        $(this).unbind("error");
                        $(this).unbind("load");
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
                image.attr("src", data.eq(i).attr("data-url"));
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I meet the same issue, just provide you the VML solution for you. However, it will just work for IE.

Comment: Could you explain your code? Why does this solve the issue of OP? *Code only* answers are not that helpful most of the time.

Comment: I down know why, maybe the VML contains all the bytes instead of loading them from IE cache for printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Print Images</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
        <style type="text/css">
        body, div, image{
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/life/public/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var data = $("td:[id^='tdImg']", window.opener.document);
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    var image = $("<image/>");
                    image.load(data.length, function(event){
                        try{
                            var c = $("<canvas />");
                            c.get(0).width = $(this).get(0).naturalWidth;
                            c.get(0).height = $(this).get(0).naturalHeight;
                            var cxt = c.get(0).getContext("2d");
                            cxt.drawImage($(this).get(0), 0, 0);
                            var base64Code = c.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
                            c.remove();
                            $("body").append($("<div/>").append($("<image/>").attr("src", base64Code)));
                            if($("body").find("image").length == event.data){
                                window.print();
                                window.close();
                            }                                           
                        }catch(e){
                            alert(e.message);
                        }finally{
                            $(this).unbind("error");
                            $(this).unbind("load");
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
                    image.attr("src", data.eq(i).attr("data-url"));
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is one html5 solution, but it cost more memory if your image is large or more enough.